# Corrupted SD Card

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, sd-card, partition-recovery

I am using Micro SD Card for OS on my Odroid micro-controller. Today I figured out that my Micro SD Card is not responding. I plug into my Laptop ( Linux OS ) and after that in other laptop ( Windows ), but both devices doesn't recognize the card. There is no respond.

So Is there a way to found what is going on with my Micro SD Card and is it possible to fix it ?

Comment: In short, no. Try to format it. If it won't, throw it away. I get through hundreds, possibly thousands of them for work & they're not worth fighting once they start to fail. Of course, never use them to store the only copy of anything… because their fail-rate is high & the data-loss potential is total.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will know it for the future! But it's not possible to format, because nothing detect it.

Comment: If nothing at all can see it, there is always the possibility that the contacts are greasy & not making good electrical connection. It's a small chance, but it's a chance...

Comment: That was the first thing which I do, but without success..

Comment: Then you now own the world's smallest drinks coaster, or use it under a wobbly table-leg ;)